# Ensure newline at EOF in RubyMine

Tags: macos, rubymine

How does one enforce a newline at end of file in RubyMine (v 4.5.3, on Mac OS)?
*e.g., similar to Sublime Text 2*

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Enable **Ensure blank line before end of file on Save** option in the `Editor` settings:

[image: Ensure blank line before end of file on Save]

Comment: In RubyMine 6, the label is "Ensure line feed at file end on save"

Answer (score 10):

### RubyMine 2021.2

*"Ensure every saved file ends with a line break"*

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In RubyMine 6 or above (on Mac OSX):

Enable '**Ensure line feed at file end on Save**' option in the `Editor` settings.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

RubyMine alongside many other editors supports the [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) standard for basic configuration.

You can enforce newlines at the end of every file by placing a file named `.editorconfig` at the root of your project:

```
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
```

It's possible to disable the setting for specific file types or filenames.

Comment: Neat! TIL about the EditorConfig standard. Thank you @Leo!

Answer (score 3):

In RubyMine 2016.2.1 you have to go to `Preferences > Editor > General > Other > Ensure line fedd at file end on Save`.
[Screenshot of the Preferences in RubyMine 2016.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nTJs.png)